# Installing web publish update in visual studio 2012 express for web

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am developing an asp .net website in visual studio express 2012 for web. I need to publish this website to another sever. But the publish option is not there in my visual studio.

On researching I found that publish option is not there because of the express edition and a kind of  'publish update' is available for visual studio. Since I am using an express edition, can I install and add that to my visual studio ? Could you please send me a download link if anyone available.

Could anyone help me ?

Comment: You could just upgrade to Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, its free (for up to 5 commercial users) and pretty much fully featured.

Comment: check publish option from solution explorer by right clicking, or look in build from menu list in vs with project name

Comment: No its not there. I already checked.

Comment: Ian,  is there any other option available other than upgrading to visual studio 2015.